# Accessing values of .summary after FBA

Tags: python, dataframe, bioinformatics, cobra

I am trying to access the values of the summary table after FBA analysis or more precisly the different flux values. I am not able to use the module cobra.flux_balance_analysis.sample.

Here is a working example

```
import cobra
from cobra.test import create_test_model
from cobra.core import Metabolite, Reaction, Model

model = create_test_model("textbook")
model.optimize()
model.summary()
```

I would like to get the float of objectives, biomass_ecoli_core.

Comment: Are you running into an error? Are you confused on how to proceed? is `model.optimizeze()` maybe called `optimize` instead?

Comment: It is called optimize. I was wondering how to access the value over python so I can write a script in which I can use the values without looking at them